# Serial port communication read function cannot read full response

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am having issues with reading complete return string after sending an "ATZ" command to my OBDII dongle device with an STN1100 chip in it. Here is the return response of sending "ATZ" command on putty:

[image: returned string on putty]

Here is my COM setting code:

```
LPCWSTR port = L"COM6";

device = CreateFile(port,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    NULL,
    0);

if (device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Failed to open port\n");
    printf("error code is %i\n", device);
    return false;
}
else 
    printf("Port is open successfully!\n");

//Settings
/*Timeout*/
COMMTIMEOUTS timeout;
timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1; 
if (!SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeout)) {
    printf("Error setting the timeout\n");
    printf("Error code: %i\n", GetLastError());
}
/**/
DCB serialParams;
serialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(serialParams);
if (!GetCommState(device, &serialParams))  //need this getCommState before setCommState
    printf("Error getting current DCB settings\n");
serialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
serialParams.ByteSize = 8;
serialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
serialParams.fOutX = FALSE;
serialParams.fInX = FALSE;
serialParams.fBinary = TRUE;
serialParams.fNull = TRUE;
serialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
if (!SetCommState(device, &serialParams)) {
    printf("Error setting the DCB\n");
    printf("Error code: %i\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Here is my Write and Read function:

```
bool Write(HANDLE device) { 
bool bErrorFlag = FALSE;
char DataBuffer[] = "ATZ\n";
//char* cmd = DataBuffer;
DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0; 

bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
    device,
    DataBuffer,
    3,
    &dwBytesWritten,
    NULL);
if (!bErrorFlag) {
    printf("Failed to write to device\n");
    printf("Error code: %i\n", GetLastError());
    return false;
}
return true;
}    
bool Read(HANDLE device) {
char ReadBuffer[256] = { 0 };
int BUFFERSIZE = 256;
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
DWORD read;
OVERLAPPED ol = { 0 };

if (!ReadFile(device, ReadBuffer, BUFFERSIZE - 1, &read, 0))
{
    printf("Terminal failure: Unable to read from device.\n GetLastError=%08x\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(device);
    return false;
}
printf("Response is %s\n", ReadBuffer);

return true;
}
```

I can only receive returned echo command "ATZ" by running the code above, does anyone know what setting I did wrong? It looks like the read function stops reading from the buffer after receiving the first line.

Comment: Try carriage return as a line ending: `"ATZ\r"`

Comment: Yeah, that code is quite wrong.  The only guarantee you get from ReadFile() is that it will return at least 1 byte.  You cannot ignore the `read` value.  And it is not a C string, you must 0-terminate it yourself.  And "\n" in printf() is wrong.  So you have to keep calling ReadFile() until the entire response is received, when you get 0x10 then you got one line.  If you don't want the modem to echo back the command then you have to send "ATE0\n".

Comment: One more thing, `WriteFile` is only trying to write 3 bytes, but `"ATZ\n"` is 4 bytes long.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles i tried your suggestion, it still returned the same echo command. update: Just change 3 to 4, the return line is still the same.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean the way I use ReadFile() is not proper in this case? Then what would be the better way to read the buffer?

Comment: The string will be 0-terminated becasue you initialize all bytes to zero in `char ReadBuffer[256] = { 0 };` and the size you pass to `ReadFile` leaves at least the last character untouched, so don't worry about that. Hans is suggesting you call `ReadFile` in a loop, because the echoed line takes up one call to `ReadFile`, so if you don't call it again, you won't see the response.